# Objective-C -- NSObject isEqual, vs. == comparison?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing objects in Obj-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054730/comparing-objects-in-obj-c)

What the difference is between these two methods of checking for object equality:

```
UIButton *btn1 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
UIButton *btn2 = [[UIButton alloc] init];
```

What is the difference between:

```
if (btn1 == btn2) {
  // Run some code
}
```

and

```
if ([btn1 isEqual:btn2]) {
  // Run some code
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The first way compares pointers, while the second way compares objects.

That is, the first way compares if the pointers have the same value. In this case it is likely that they don't, in the second case the objects will be compared. Since they are initialized the same way they could be equal. (Note, it appears that with the `UIButton`'s implementation of `isEqual:` the result is always false.)

In most cases using `==` is not what you want. However, what is appropriate depends on your objective.

Comment: **objects are likely to be equal??** how? they will be entirely different objects..

Comment: He answered your question pretty well. Maybe you could clarify what part you want to understand better, or give an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @noa I updated my answer from my original one. My original answer was brief.

Comment: downvote for saying **in the second case the objects will be compared. Since they are initialized the same way they are likely to be equal.**.. From the question, no way `[btn1 isEqual:btn2]` to return `true`. So they are **not equal**

Comment: @Krishnabhadra I've updated my answer. The implementation of `isEqual:` depends on the class. In the case of `UIButton` (and most likely `UIView`) it doesn't return true for different instances. However, in other cases, for example with `NSMutableString`, if the value of the strings are equal then the method will return true.

Comment: Just to let you know, the default IMPL of isEqual compares object hashes (which means objects created, archived, then dearchived (NSCoding) should be equal.

Comment: Instead of "pointers" and "objects" you may want to use the technical terms *identity* and *equality*. `==` asks if they are identical (are they the same object instance) while `isEqual` asks if they are equal (where sometimes, depending on type semantics, two separate instances are considered equal).

Answer (score 15):

Prateek's answer and Thomas's edited answer is correct. But I just want to add a common pitfall/confusion when dealing with this type of cases..

Consider this case

```
 NSString *str1  = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
 NSString *str2  = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hello"];
```

Ideally `str1` and `str2` should be 2 different string objects, str1 and str2 should be pointing to different addresses. But running below code prints `str1 == str2`

```
if(str1 == str2){
    NSLog(@"str1 == str2");
}
```

and below code prints `str1 isEqual str2`

```
if([str1 isEqual:str2]){
    NSLog(@"str1 isEqual str2");
}
```

The reason is, the **two identical string literal passed through `initWithString` will have the same address to start**, so they are the same object too (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605851/why-are-these-two-nsstring-pointers-the-same)). This is the optimization of constant data, which is a feature in iOS (and many other implementation I feel).

But this won't work for other kind of objects/classes. When you create 2 `UIButton` they will entirely different objects and both `btn1` and `btn2` (see the question) will points to different address.

Comment: On 64 bit systems, this happens actually in many cases. NSNumber, NSIndexPath, NSDate, and NSString with short values often have the same pointer when they are equal. There is only one [NSNull null], only one @ [], only one @ YES and one @ NO.

Answer (score 5):

Mentioned difference in comments

```
if (btn1 == btn2) //This compared your pointers
{
  // Run some code
}
```

and

```
if ([btn1 isEqual:btn2]) //Compares UIButton object
{
  // Run some code
}
```