# check which UIButton was tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have created a several buttons like this:

```
[self makeButtonsWithX:0.0f y:180.0f width:640.0f height:80.0f color:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.796 green:0.282 blue:0.196 alpha:1] button:self.redButton];

    [self makeButtonsWithX:0.0f y:260.0f width:640.0f height:80.0f color:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.761 green:0.631 blue:0.184 alpha:1] button:self.yellowButton];
```

using this function:

```
- (void)makeButtonsWithX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height color:(UIColor *)color button:(UIButton *)button
{
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    button.backgroundColor = color;
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

When I tap one of them I want to know which one was tapped, using this function:

```
- (void)tappedButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    //NSLog(@"tapped");
    if ([button isEqual:self.redButton]) {
        NSLog(@"Red");
    }
}
```

Nothing happens. If I uncomment the first NSLog in the last function however, it prints every time I press a button (doesn't matter which one). Why isn't my if-statement working?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating the buttons, give them unique tags.

Change your `tappedButton:` method to this:

```
- (void)tappedButton:(id)sender {
    if([sender tag] == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Red");
    }
}
```

And I'd probably create an `enum` for the tags:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ButtonTags) {
    ButtonUnknown = 100,
    ButtonRedTag = 101,
    ButtonBlueTag = 102,
    ButtonGreenTag = 103,
    ButtonYellowTag = 104,
    ButtonWhiteTag = 105
};
```

Now use the `enum` both when setting and checking the tags.

```
if([sender tag] == ButtonRedTag)
```

To set a tag:

```
[button setTag:ButtonRedTag];
```

---

There may be another way of determine which button was pressed, but as far as I'm concerned, using `[sender tag];` is the best method.  Consider this... suppose you want to call a method either when a button is pressed or a text field has resigned first responder?  For example, imagine a login page, with a username/password text field and a button for login and create new account.  Using sender tag, you can EASILY make all your UI elements at least start in the same method:

```
- (void)handleUserInteraction:(id)sender {
    switch([sender tag]) {
        case LoginButtonTag:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case PasswordTextFieldTag:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case NewAccountButtonTag:
            // do stuff
            break;
        case BackgroundViewTappedTag:
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

It might make more sense to just hook all of these UI elements up to different methods in the first place, and certainly, within the `switch`, they should call out to different methods, but suppose there's some bit of logic you want to execute in all 4 of these cases?  Put it just before or just after the `switch` instead of putting it in all 4 of the methods you've created for handling these different cases, etc.

Comment: Nice one! Thanks :) But do you know why my function don't work the way it is? isEqual is comparing two uibutton objects?

Comment: According to this StackOverflow answer, `isEqual:` always returns false for `UIButton`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14036622/2792531 Anyway, there may be another way to compare buttons, but using tags really is the best way to determine which UI element we're looking at.

Comment: @Nilzone- I added an edit explaining why you might want to get into the habit of using `[sender tag]` even for ui elements that might be comparable using `[foo isEqual:bar]`.

Comment: I'm new to IOS programming. Where would it be appropriate to put the NSEnum?

Comment: Right after the `#import` lines in the `.m` file.  Also, the first word should be `typedef`, not just `type`.

Comment: thanks! one last probably silly question. Why would you start at 100, 101 etc.. or is that completely random?

Comment: Somewhat random.  I don't start at 0 for tags.  But basically, I might make my button tags be 100-105, my text field tags are 200-210, etc.  Each type of UIElement starts at a different increment of 100.  And it's just my personal preference.

Comment: What's wrong with `button === self.redButton`? Simple and readable.

Comment: First, there's no `===`.  Second, enumerated tags is just as readable.  Third, you can't use a switch on a button, but you can on a tag (and switches increase readability versus an if/else structure in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you cannot pass the button "to make" by reference. The way you call `makeButtonsWithX` will to not change self.redButton.
self.redButton in the if statement will be nil.
Change the return type of `make ButtonsWithX` from `(void)`to `(UIButton *)` and do it like this:

```
self.redButton = [self makeButtonsWithX: ...
```