# Comparing UI object in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, textview

I am making a super class to TableView, I will have static TextView in it and also I have TextView in cells.

Then I starting edit my TextView in Cell I assign it to static property of TableView.

Now I need go thought cells subviews, compare 2 textView (static and textView in cell) and find cell.

How can I compare 2 textViews?

I can not compare its texts because then some text did typed I lost event.

Comment: Could you please describe the real problem you are trying to solve? Assigning things to static properties is rather suspicious, let alone comparing UI elements.

Comment: Code. Must see code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to compare pointers to find if your cell object is the same as the static one, you can use the `==` sign to compare it. In some other cases you can use NSObject's `isEqual:` method to check if they are "the same" (where "same" meaning may vary according to object type you are trying to compare)

You can read more about comparison types on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054730/comparing-objects-in-obj-c)